# Change IP address (proxy) with test

Tags: php, proxy, ip

I want to browse some sites using a proxy, so I want to change the IP address of my client to the specified IP.

I am also testing it on `localhost`, so my goal is to visit my localhost site with PHP script (also localhost). The problem is how to test this (maybe some simple test by writing out changed IP to file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you mean, but you can check your clients IP address with this:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

echo $ip;
```

Ofcourse this will not change your clients IP address. You need an actual proxy server for that.

Comment: I looked for some proxy and I found some site which provides some ips as proxy. Is that what I need?

Comment: No.. you need to setup your browser to use that proxy. Php has nothing to do with that. You can only use this code to check if the proxy is working..

Comment: But I want to visit (by using PHP, maybe curl) another site with pretending other ip (proxy), so another (source) site will see new ip. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible? Yes. But it's not something so easily done. As we are here to help you with code (not write it for you!), I'll give you a link to some script that makes it possible. But from there you're on your own: https://github.com/drumstok/proxy